# How can I make an unordered list that alternates between post types?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have a two post types in my wordpress site -- a team member post type, and a project post type. I'd like to make an alternating unordered list that displays the thumbnail and title for each post type but can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this. For clarity I want something like this as the output:

Project 1

Team Member 1

Project 2

Team Member 2

My code is below. Any help would be very appreciated!

```
        <ul class="callout">
                    <?php $args = array('showposts' => 2, 'post_type' => 'team_member', 'orderby' => 'rand' );  
                    $team_members = get_posts($args); ?>

                    <?php $args = array('showposts' => 2, 'post_type' => 'project');
                    $projects = get_posts($args); ?>

                        <?php foreach($projects as $post) : 
                            setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                            <?php $project_img = the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' ); ?>
                            <?php echo $project_img; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                        <?php foreach($team_members as $post) :
                            setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
                            <?php $photo = get_field('team_member_photo'); ?>
                            <?php $image_size = 'thumbnail'; ?>
                            <?php $image = $photo['sizes'][$image_size]; ?>
                            <?php $name = get_the_title(); ?>
                            <?php $name = explode(" ", $name); ?>
                            <?php $name = array_shift($name); ?>                        
                        <?php endforeach; 
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>




            </ul>  <!-- .callout -->
```

Comment: Can you update your question to show a brief example of what you'd want the rendered HTML to look like?

Comment: Rather than use `foreach` to loop over them, use a `for` loop, and index the arrays; or, `foreach` over the `$projects` array, and use its indices for the `$members` array.

Comment: Sure @mkaatman, something like this --

`<li>
  <a href="/team">
  <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>"> (team member image here)
  </a>
  <span>Hi I'm <?php echo $name; ?>!</span>
</li>  

<li>
  <a href="/projects">
  <img src="<?php echo $featured_image; ?>"> (project post featured image here)
  </a>
  <span>View All Projects</span>
</li>`

Comment: @alanlittle not sure I know what you mean when you say "use its indices for the $members array" -- can you explain this?

Comment: Ultimately you need to move your 2nd loop inside the first. As you loop through teams you want to loop through the members and display them all.

Comment: @AFarkas I'm assuming your project and team member arrays correspond one-to-one, in which case, you would construct your `foreach` to retrieve the index of the projects array: `foreach ($projects as $idx => $post)` then in the loop reference `$team_members[$idx]`